# ORA-08102 while creating a view

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

I am learning PL/SQL programming. I'm trying to create a view with the following statement:

```
create or replace view viewName as select ID from employees;
```

The view creation throws the following error:

```
ORA-00604 error occurred at recursive level 1
ORA-08102 Index not found, obj #39 , file 1 block 61248
```

How can I fix it?

The problem is with all objects, procedures,functions,views and i am using the HR Database of Oracle 11G for learning purposes.

Comment: how did u "create a schema" using SQL or PL/SQL?   please show us the command.   hope this help:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054389/how-to-create-new-schema-and-list-all-schema-name-in-oracle

Comment: Create or replace View viewName as select ID from employees; No Statements sense to work.

Answer (score 1):

File 1 belongs to the SYSTEM tablespace.
Objects with such low id as 39 are dictionary objects. For example in my database it is an index of OBJ$ (I_OBJ4). ORA-08102 also points us towards an index, which seems to be corrupt based on the error you get.

Find the index name by:

```
select object_name from dba_objects where object_id = 39;
```

Unfortunately you will not be able to rebuild this index (ORA-00701), but you can recreate it:

```
shutdown immediate
startup upgrade
alter session set nls_length_semantics=byte;
@?/rdbms/admin/utlmmig
```

Comment: your answer sounds logical for me :-).

Comment: I have this issue.  I_OBJ4 index of OBJ$ is corrupt and I cannot rebuild or drop the index.  When I try your solution above, it gives me the same error when running the utlmmig: ORA-08102: index key not found, obj# 148225, file 1, block 5699.

Comment: and now even worse, the database won't start.  Database mounted.
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39714: upgrade script utlmmig.sql failed

Comment: solved it by doing: delete from props$ where name='BOOTSTRAP_UPGRADE_ERROR';